# Incorrect proof of the Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, open-map

I was following the proof of the Open Mapping Theorem in Lang's *Real and Functional Analysis* and something odd happened. I was able to simplify a lot his proof. Not only that, but I was able to improve the theorem itself. My proof is valid for any normed space, not only Banach spaces. Of course I know this can't be the case, but still, I wasn't able to find where my proof got wrong. If you spot the mistake, please tell me.

**Open Mapping Theorem:** Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and let $f:X \to Y$ be a linear continuous map. If $f$ is surjective, then it is also open.

**Proof:** For any $s>0$, we will denote $B_s = \{ x\in X:\ \|x\| < s \}$ and $C_s = \{ y \in Y:\ \|y\| < s \}$.

First, note that since $X$ is surjective, we have $$ f(X) = f(\cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n) = Y.$$
Also, note that $s < t \implies B_s \subset B_t$. In particular, this means that $\cup_{n=1}^N B_n \subset B_t$, for any $t > N$. Then for any $r > 0$, there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $C_r \subset f(B_{kr})$.

Now let $U \subset X$ be an open set and let $x \in U$ be an arbitrary point. By definition, there is a $t > 0$ such that $x + B_t \subset U$. Then $$f(x+B_t) = f(x) + f(B_t) \subset f(U).$$

Given any $r>0$, we know there is a $k \in \mathbb{K}$ such that $C_r \subset f(B_{kr})$. The it follows that $$f(B_t) = f\left(\frac{t}{kr} B_{kr}\right) = \frac{t}{kr} f(B_{kr}) \supset \frac{t}{kr} C_r = C_\frac{t}{k}.$$

Therefore, $$f(x) + C_\frac{t}{r} \subset f(x) + f(B_t) \subset f(U). $$

This proves $f(x)$ is in the interior of $f(U)$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we conclude that every point of $f(U)$ is in its interior, so $f(U)$ is open. $\hspace{1cm}\square$

Thank you!

Comment: Can i suggest a title change to "Incorrect proof of the Open Mapping Theorem." It would seem to be better for archival purposes on the site, and, after all, mistakes in our own proofs always tend to be difficult for us to spot (otherwise we probably wouldn't have made them in the first place!).

Comment: No problem. :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(\bigcup_n B_n)=Y$ does not implies there exists $l$ such that  $C_r\subset f(B_l)$, the image of a ball is not always a ball.

Comment: I didn't say *for any*. What I said is that given $r>0$, *there is* a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $C_r \subset f(B_{kr})$.

Comment: Take $kr=l$, you have $C_r\subset f(B_l)$.

Comment: Still, what I said translates to *there is* $l > 0$ such that $C_r \subset f(B_l)$. Not *any* $l>0$.

Comment: Why such a $l$ exists?

Comment: The image of ball doesn't have to be a ball, indeed. But this is not important to my argument. The important thing is that I assumed $f(B_l)$ would contain $C_r$. Now I got my error, I assumed that would be a ball $B_l$ in $X$ such that $B_l \supset f^{-1}(C_r)$. I used the fact that the ball in the domain can be arbitrarily large, but the preimage of balls in $Y$ can be unlimited in $X$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I pointed out in my answer, I said that the image of a ball is not always a ball, because is that was true, your argument would have been true too.

Comment: Closed case. :)

Comment: Just a little thing. The image of a ball under a linear map is not necessarily a ball even in the finite dimensional case (it is a ellipsoid). I think the problem is that f(B) is not absorbing (this definition is given in Rudin's book, not sure if Lang talks about It).